# How can I use asynchronous ajax call using jQuery in javascript using a single function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a javascript function multiple times in my javascript code. Inside my javascript there is a jQuery Ajax call. What is happening now is while one function call is going on, another function started hit that function and I got some error. When I try to make that Ajax call synchronous, it works fine to me.

Any one have any idea how to call same function with Ajax asynchronously having Ajax call inside it. same function may be called in same time.

Comment: Please show your code. And what error did you get?

Comment: So do you want multiple AJAX calls firing off at once, or do you want a single AJAX call firing at any one time?

Comment: Show your code please